# Boundary conditions for compressible Euler equations

Tags: boundary-conditions, numerical-modelling

I want to solve the compressible 1D Euler equations numerically.

Theory says that for subsonic inflows, one can prescribe two variables, e.g. pressure and temperature. Density can then be computed with the equation of state, but how is the velocity calculated?

For subsonic outflows only one variable can be prescribed. Also here my question is: how to compute the remaining variables?

Comment: I believe that your assertion is wrong. For subsonic inflow, you need to prescribe all three variables. For subsonic outflow, all non-prescribed variables have values determined by the equation.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I am not quite sure about your answer. Can you elaborate about it regarding characteristic theory?

Comment: @ConvexHull I'm actually quite certain. I'd put the onus on OP to support their statement about the two prescribable values with a reference.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I am seeing conflicting references but I might be misinterpreting them. In _Boundary Conditions for Euler Equations_ by Benzoni-Gavage and Coulombel it is stated that one can prescribe for example pressure and temperature or velocity and temperature.

Comment: You need to be able to prescribe all primary variables, and which these are depends on your formulation. These could be momentum+density+pressure (and then temperature can be computed from density + pressure) or velocity+pressue+temperature (and then density can be computed from temperature + pressure, and the momentum from that.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Maybe we are just passing each other by. It should be clear that all values for the boundary conditions must be specified. But the question is more about whether this is done in a totally independent way from the solution itself. This is definitely not the case for subsonic boundary conditions and depends on the eigenvalues of the system with which the information propagates. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002199919090152Q